# Avconv - create video from image for a specific number of frames

Tags: video, avconv

I'm trying to create a video from a single image using `avconv` for a specific number of frames.  I am using the `loop' option, but I can only specify the time I want the video to be in terms of seconds.  I am currently running the following command:

```
    avconv -loop 1 -i image.jpg -t 10 output.avi
```

In the documentation, the `-t` option is stated as the following:

‘-t duration (output)’
Stop writing the output after its duration reaches duration. duration may be a number in seconds, or in hh:mm:ss[.xxx] form.

Does the "[.xxx]" parameter mean frames?

Update:  I run the following code now:

```
    avconv -loop 1 -f image2 -i 1.jpg -t 00:00:00.4 -r 25 please_work.avi
```

Then I run the following to extract the frames from the video I created to see if it's the right number of frames:

```
   avconv -i please_work.avi %d.jpg
```

I end up getting 10 .jpg images instead of 4.  Are the parameters I set incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

The [.xxx] portion of the timestamp is in terms of milliseconds. So, if you want a specific number of frames, you multiply it by the frame rate (16.67) in the case for 60fps.

So if you want 50 frames of video at 60 fps, you multiply 50 * 16.67 = 833 [truncated as an integer] and set it to the string: 00:00:00.[833]

The following command achieves tiis:

```
    avconv -loop 1 -f image2 -i 1.jpg -t 00:00:00.833 -r 60 -shortest  please_work.avi

    frame=   50 fps=  0 q=2.0 Lsize=     130kB time=0.83 bitrate=1276.7kbits/s
```